# Exporting Histogram from Python to Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm pretty new to coding and I need to some help with exporting data or just printing it on the python shell.
The code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import openpyxl

data = pd.read_excel('/Users/user/Desktop/Data/Book1.xlsx')
df = data.hist(bins=40)
plt.xlim([0,1000])
plt.title('Data')
plt.xlabel('Neuron')
plt.ylabel('# of Spikes')
plt.show()
```

So the code makes a histogram after binning the data into 40 bins, the range of the 0 to 1558.5 or so. What I'm trying to do is export the data AFTER binning since when I try writing:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/Users/user/Desktop/Data/output.xlsx')
df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2')
writer.save()
```

it saves the original data and not the data that has the histogram applied and has the bins applied. Also, if I can get some help in how to change the number of bins in a range from 0 to 5, 5 to 10, etc. basically it reads in intervals of 5, all the way towards the end of the data, so it'll eventually stop at the last bit of data and stick that data into a bin. Any help is appreciated and it doesn't have to be specifically pandas. Thank you. By the way I think what I made was a Dataframe from the imported data, again just a beginner so not so sure.

Comment: You are converting a variable named "df1" to excel.  But your histogram is in a variable named "df".

Answer (score 3):

The line `df = data.hist(bins=40)` does not actually create a DataFrame of binned data. `df` ends up holding a numpy `ndarray` that contains a `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot` object.

One way to save the binned data is to create the histogram via matplotlib's `hist()`. Add the following lines directly after your `read_excel` line:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
counts, bins, bars = plt.hist(data.values, bins=40)
df = pd.DataFrame({'bin_leftedge': bins[:-1], 'count': counts})
```

Then, as pointed out in a comment, be sure to change `df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2')` to `df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2')`.

`bins` contains the edges of each bin, so the `bins` array will have one more element than the `counts` array. Keep in mind that the above code associates each count with the *left* edge of that count's bin, and does not save the rightmost bin edge.

There may be a better or pandas-idiomatic way to do this, but hopefully the above meets your needs.

---

**EDIT: integer bin widths**

You can pass a `list` of bin edges as `bins=` to either `data.hist()` or `plt.hist()`. To create bins of width 5 that start at 0 and include the maximum value of the data, this should work:

```
counts, bins, patches = plt.hist(data.values, bins=range(0, max(data.values)+5, 5))
```

Explanation: Python's built-in `range(start, stop, step)` accepts only integers, and returns a list that *includes* the left endpoint (`start`) but *excludes* the right endpoint (`stop`). (In math notation, `range(start, stop, step)` returns evenly spaced integers on the half-open interval `[start, stop)`.) The `+5` in the above line ensures that the last bin's right edge ends up on the righthand side of the maximum data value.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, but when I do as you suggested I get an error:                                                                                            
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\This one.py", line 7, in <module>
    counts, bins, patches = plt.hist(data.values, bins=range(0, max(data.values)+5, 5))
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index      How can I fix this?

Comment: @J.Garcia, sorry - my test cases used integers, whereas you probably have floating-point data. Try wrapping `int(...)` around `max(data.values)` to cast the `stop` parameter of `range` to an integer:


`counts, bins, patches = plt.hist(data.values, bins=range(0, int(max(data.values))+5, 5))`

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked, however, I hope you can help me with one last thing if I want to make the bins, bin=[a,a+◇t) where a is the left most bin and ◇ t (Delta t) is the bin width would I have to define ◇t  as a function?

Comment: @J.Garcia - no need to define deltaT as a function; it just needs to be an integer, if you use the built-in `range()` function. (For floating-point ranges, look into `numpy`'s `arange()` function, but I don't see that being too applicable to histogram x-axes.) But if you have to automatically generate multiple plots, you might want to write a function to calculate some desirable deltaT without having to manually hard-code it every time.